# Need IIS 7 Url Rewrite Version 1.1 Regex Help To Remove Folder From Url

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am using:

**IIS 7**
**Url Rewrite Module Version 1.1**
**Asp.Net MVC 4**

I am hosting my sites in a shared hosting environment.
No site is hosted in the root folder as all sites are in their own physical folder and I use the domain name of the site as the physical folder name.

I would like to change my urls from this

```
  http://www.mysite1.com/mysite1
  http://mysite1.com/mysite1
```

to this

```
  http://www.mysite1.com/ 
  http://mysite1.com/
```

I have this and it doesn't work.

```
    **DOES NOT WORK**
    <rule name="RemoveFolder" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="mysite1/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

**Can someone give me a regular expression that would add www to any urls and remove the folder that is showing up in the url?**

Answer (score 1):

OK. What I typed below, doesn't work for me. I thought it did, but I realized it didn't.
@Cheesemacfly, I'm trying to remove the subfolder from the url, 
Redirect the user back to the site with the url MINUS the subfolder,
Make sure that there is NOT a continuous loop.

---

Cheesemacfly, your answer didn't work, but it did put me on the path to the full correct answer.

Thank you chesse for putting me on the right path.
This rule removes the subfolder from the url and redirects the user back to the page without the subfolder. The condition makes sure that I don't have a continual redirect. Once the url has been rewritten, that conditional will stop the url from matching again.

I placed this rule in the ROOT web.config of my hosting account.
The root ONLY contains a web.config and all of the subfolders.

```
    <rule name="Cleanup" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="theFolderINeedToRemove/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mywebsite.com/theFolderINeedToRemove$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```